# How would it be possible to do a master's in astrophysics with a bachelor in software engineering?

Tags: masters, computer-science, physics, changing-fields

## Introduction

To orient you, it would be better If I gave some extra information here. imagine someone in their studies of software engineering has found out about the applications of ML in the field of astrophysics and has developed an interest in that area where the two intersect, however, they understand that just knowing some ML algorithms won't suffice for an academic pursuit in astrophysics so they very likely require a bachelor's degree in physics in order to proceed with that ambition.

## The Crux

That being said, I'm curious to know whether it's realistic for this person to either:

- Complete their master's degree in AI.
- Form their thesis around the applications of ML in astrophysics while
  studying relevant books to their thesis (improve their knowledge of
  astrophysics).
- Eventually, pursue a Ph.D. focused on astrophysics.

or

- Continue with their studies in AI and keep astronomy at a hobby level.

Moreover, I understand that people from several engineering and non-engineering disciplines work alongside astrophysicists such as aerospace engineers, hardware engineers, or astrobiologists but which path do you think would help someone with such a background to eventually get a job related to astronomy or more specifically contribute to projects on the outer solar system exploration missions (JUICE, Juno, Cassini–Huygens). Also, I forgot to mention that the person in question prefers a route that ultimately helps them become a scholar and teach or research in some university as well.

### Rambling Thoughts

Although I have found some really good answers in this other similar [post](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/48882/for-what-aspects-of-cosmology-research-can-a-software-engineer-contribute) such as [this](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/48961/50390) and [this one](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/48891/50390) that encourage a way of collaborating with established astrophysicists while using my SWE skills, I think that realistically speaking, it's not what I as a junior programmer might be able to achieve within a practical scope of time, that is from the age of 23 to 35. I might be wrong for thinking this way but in my belief, an academic environment offers a more rigorous and certain path towards becoming an astrophysicist. I should also make it clear that what I deeply want is a well-rounded academic life. I've realized that I love exploration and using the scientific method more than just writing code but that doesn't mean I find software development boring or ordinary.

In light of these considerations, I invite you to provide alternative perspectives and guidance on this matter.

## TL;DR:

someone with a bachelor in software engineering is weighing the possibilities of becoming an astrophysicist or an AI engineer working in a position related to astrophysics and cosmology.

Comment: Absolutely not. The simplest of mathematics in astrophysics requires mathematical physics that most CS graduates at the undergraduate level do not have.

Comment: @Academia.jpg Your answer partially answers my question, however, I wish you could elaborate further. It's understandable that astrophysics requires more mathematical reasoning than CS but this doesn't help me progress towards the goal in question.

Comment: You are taking for granted the goals can be achieved based on your current status - you can't. Astrophysics is one of the most nightmarish area in which you deal with classical mechanics, lots of tensors, computational physics with, depending, chemistry.

Comment: @Academia.jpg Well, I don't want to disagree with the fact that Astrophysics is indeed one of the most frightening fields with subjects such as those you mentioned, and I don't want to pretend that I'm more familiar with them than you are. still, I want to contribute to it in as slightest and meaningful a way as possible.

Comment: Where would you want to study? Country or countries? How mathematical was your undergraduate degree? Lots of CS theory or more applied? Lots of math?

Comment: @Buffy I'd like to study in Italy or Germany. Regarding your second question I'd say I had plenty of math and statistics courses such as:
General Mathematics (3 credits),
Applied Mathematics (4 credits),
Statistics and Probability (2 credits),
Electricity and Magnetism (2 credits),
Engineering Probability and Statistics (2 credits),
Differential Equations (2 credits),
Discrete Mathematics (2 credits),
Engineering Mathematics (2 credits),
but I surely wouldn't say that these are on par with the amount of math that one might receive in a math or physics bachelor programme.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with the off-the bat comments by Academia.jpg. As someone who is in academia doing interdisciplinary research, it is all about finding the right institutions and right people who precisely encourage interdisciplinary collaboration. I know that there are several faculty at my PhD institution who hold [dual appointments](https://cmse.msu.edu/Directory/index.aspx?group=145) in Astrophysics and Scientific Computing.

If you are serious about going into an astrophysics graduate degree, look for interdisciplinary faculty who have exciting research questions. Look what they do. And if you see yourself capable of contributing to their work, then shoot them an email asking them if they would consider taking you as a student. In the email be very clear about how you would fit in their lab.

My institution is not the only one promoting interdisciplinary research. There are many more around. You just have to look for them.

Comment: I've already contacted a few professors and one of them, who's mostly doing research in Chemical Engineering suggested that I do my own studies on astrophysics and gradually shift my focus onto that field. he also suggested that I choose an interdisciplinary master's thesis since I'm interested in using ML in that area.
Nonetheless, I assume that you mean that I go self-taught and start making connections with faculties whose work makes sense to me and I join them that way. If that's true, would I still need a bachelor's in physics or something like that to prove my competence?

Comment: I agree with this and strongly disagree with the comments by Academia.jpg. I think someone with a computer science bachelors degree has strong chance of being able to pursue an MSc degree in Astrophysics.  In the UK at least, there are several MSc Astrophysics programs for which the prerequisites seem to align with your background. Sure, some of the courses will likely prove to be more demanding than for someone with a more physics-based undergraduate degree, so will require more effort. There are also MSc that are primarily by research that you could look into.

Comment: @Navid What I meant is that you look for professors that have dual appointments, say they are faculty at both Astrophysics and Computer Science departments. If they have a successful research portfolio, chances are that their institution facilitates interdisciplinary work, at least between CS and Physics. Contact them if you find their research interesting. Tell them how you think you can contribute. And hopefully, they will indicate you what is the least painful way (with institutional support) to put you up to speed in whatever physics/math content you are lacking right now.

Comment: @EA304GT Thank you for taking the time to provide me with further clarification. I appreciate your help and guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can do a Masters project in astrophysics, if you focus on machine learning. After all, in machine learning, the things you care about (loss function, CNNs, etc.) are field-independent. Once you're familiar with the concepts (and your professor can help you identify which observables to look at), you can apply ML techniques anywhere.

However an astrophysics MSc will usually also involve other stuff, most importantly coursework, which you have little chance of passing. E.g. here's the [syllabus](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/8-901-astrophysics-i-spring-2006/pages/syllabus/) of a graduate-level stellar physics course. The formal prerequisites are Thermodynamics and Statistical Mechanics & Quantum Mechanics II, neither of which you are likely to know.

> - Complete their master's degree in AI.
> - Form their thesis around the applications of ML in astrophysics while studying relevant books to their thesis (improve their knowledge of astrophysics).
> - Eventually, pursue a Ph.D. focused on astrophysics.

This is plausible, but you might need longer than other students to finish, since you'll have a lot of coursework to catch up with. You'll surely learn something about astrophysics if you work on applications of ML in astrophysics, but you will still be missing stuff like thermodynamics, statistical mechanics, and quantum mechanics, which will close off large sections of the field from you. You might also want to ask about dual supervision (one supervisor from the CS department, another from the physics/astronomy department), and attend a university where that is possible.

Comment: I've checked out the syllabus that you've included in your answer and indeed your concerns are aligned with @Academia.jpg's regarding the likelihood of me being able to pass the coursework. However, I think interdisciplinary research is the common denominator of your answer and the one above yours.

Comment: It appears that the OP should be enrolled into a CS department and work on computation - related task rather than asking how he can swing into a physics department (in which the end goal is to DO physics) to do computational - related work while doing his best to avoid physics.

My experience with CS graduates is that they tend to assume they can get by the other more technical fields. It appears the OP is looking for validation rather than a reality check.

Answer (score 0):

Both in the US and in Europe, it is not unusual to switch areas after getting a BS or MS degree, and to read for PhD in a somewhat different field. Here "somewhat" means that the education gap can be mended by taking remedial undergraduate courses. Many US universities do permit their graduate students to take such courses.

Most definitely, in the eyes of some astrophysics professors your education in computing will be a big advantage that may overweigh the lack of a Bachelors degree in Physics.

(1) As one possibility, you may consider contacting some astrophysics professors, asking them this specific question if their school would permit you to take remedial undergraduate courses in physics, if you become a graduate student there.  Also, ask them to send you the curriculum of the graduate courses at their department, then look up the related textbooks, and evaluate your ability to understand this material. (Perhaps, you should read up some of that stuff while doing your Masters in computing?)  Overall, the transition will be difficult but, in principle, doable.

(2) Aside from astrophysics, there exist such cognate areas as celestial mechanics (a branch of astronomy) and orbital mechanics (a branch of aerospace engineering). In these areas, your computing background would be very highly valued, and the transition may be a bit easier. I know someone working in that field.

(3) One more possibility would be getting a Masters or, better, PhD degree in computing, and then seeking employment at NASA (if you are in the US) or at DLR (if in Europe).

My observatory sometimes hires people with your kind of background (even without PhD). You are welcome to get in touch with me, if you wish. You will find my e-mail at my webpage.